# Kinetic energy of a falling object in water

Tags: energy

I am considering the impact energy of an object falling vertically downward with impact velocity $v$ in water. The mass of the object is $m$, and the hydrodynamic added mass from the displaced water is "$m_a$". I believe the kinetic energy at impact is 
$$KE=\frac 1 2 (m+m_a) v^2$$

However I am slightly troubled by the buoyancy force F from the displaced volume $V$ of water $F=pgV$, where $p$ is the density of water and $g$ is acceleration due to gravity. The greater the buoyancy force, the slower the object will accelerate downwards, and the easier it will be to lift. So the object can be considered to dynamically have an effective mass of $m'=m-pV$.

So is the KE in fact 
$$KE= \frac 1 2 (m'+m_a) v*v$$
I don't think so, but if I was sure I wouldn't be asking.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Prior to entering the water:**

Assume that just prior to entering the water the object has a Kinetic Energy KE of:

$KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

**2. During impact:**

During impact and entering the water the object abruptly loses some of its KE. We know this because:

1. The impact is accompanied by sound (which contains energy).
2. Water is being 'kicked up', which requires kinetic energy.
3. From the site of impact a circular surface water wave is emitted. Water waves carry kinetic energy.

In general we can say that the object loses an amount of KE, $\Delta KE$, so that its adjusted speed is:

$v'=\sqrt{(2m(KE-\Delta KE))}$

**3. After impact:**

[image: Submerged object]

Once the object is fully submersed in the water it is subject to three forces:

1. Gravity, $mg$.
2. Archimedic buoyancy, $F_b=\rho g V$, with $\rho$ density of water and $V$ the volume of the object.
3. Drag force $F_d$.

The drag force $F_d$ depends on several factors including object shape and fluid viscosity but for a perfectly spherical object the drag force obeys Stokes Law:

$F_d=6 \pi \eta\ Rv'$, with $\eta$ the kinematic viscosity of water, $R$ the radius of the sphere and $v'$ the velocity of the sphere.

Gravity $mg$ and buoyancy can be combined into a resultant gravitational force $mg-F_b=(\rho' - \rho)gV$, with $\rho'$ the density of the object.

The Equation of Motion of the submersed object (in the case of a sphere) can now be written as:

$ma=(\rho' - \rho)gV-6 \pi \eta\ Rv'$

The Stokes drag force causes the object to slow down until it reaches a constant speed, know as the *terminal velocity* **$v_t$**, at which $a=0$, so that the terminal velocity $v_t$ can be calculated from:

**$(\rho' - \rho)gV-6 \pi \eta\ Rv_t=0$** (for a perfect sphere).

**$v_t=\frac{(\rho' - \rho)gV}{6 \pi \eta\ R}$**

Comment: Gert, thanks for the comprehensive answer. Shouldn't there be an added mass force in your equation of motion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass)? On reflection my original post was badly phrased as I was interested in the latter part of your answer i.e. a falling body impact a body on the seabed. I think the impacted body will also feel the kinetic energy of this added mass (at least to some extent).

Comment: I'm really not sure how the $\frac{\rho_c V_p}{2} \frac{Du}{Dt}$ part would have to be applied here, Pseudo Nym.